# Web services page to display purchase orders from last 2 years

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, dynamics-business-central

I'm trying to make a web services page to display purchase orders from last 2 years

What I did right now is a table with the same fields as "Purchase Lines" and an automated process that will filter "Purchase Lines" from last 2 years, loop all lines and TRANSFERFIELDS to my new table. Then I just created a default page with the wizard for my new table and add it to web services.

[image]

Is it possible to specify a filter in the page for example in SourceTableView property to display only "Purchase Lines" from last 2 years so I can do just 1 page to get rid of the automated process and the extra table?

Comment: Yes. You can just add a filter using `setfilter` on `OnOpenPage` trigger.

Answer (score 0):

On the `OnOpenPage` trigger, you can specify this filter

```
Rec.SetRange("Order Date", CalcDate('<-2Y>', Today()), 0D);
```